# SonarQube 5.3 stopped analyzing Github pull requests

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have recently updated our SonarQube version from 5.0 to 5.3 and our SonarQube Scanner/Runner from 2.3 to 2.4.

During this upgrade, SonarQube has stopped analyzing our GitHub pull requests. We run the SonarQube Scanner as the last step in our jenkins job.

The command we run is as follows:

```
/usr/local/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues \
     -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=${ghprbPullId} \
     -Dsonar.github.repository=OurRepository/OurRepository \
     -Dsonar.github.login=MyUsername \
     -Dsonar.github.oauth=MyToken \
     -Dsonar.login=MyUsername \
     -Dsonar.password=MyPassword \
     -Dsonar.sources=./app/ \
     -Dsonar.projectKey=MyProject \
     -Dsonar.projectName=MyProject \
     -Dsonar.projectVersion=2.9.0 \
     -Dsonar.exclusions=app/Vendor/**,app/Plugin/**/Test/**,app/Test/**
```

The only thing we changed during this upgrade is the analysis mode. Before the upgrade we used the incremental mode which has been removed in 5.2.

The output of the command is as follows:

```
+ /usr/local/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=issues -Dsonar.github.pullRequest=2944 -Dsonar.github.repository=OurRepository/OurRepository -Dsonar.github.login=Username -Dsonar.github.oauth=MyToken -Dsonar.login=MyUsername -Dsonar.password=MyPAsword -Dsonar.sources=./app/ -Dsonar.projectKey=MyProject -Dsonar.projectName=MyProject -Dsonar.projectVersion=2.9.0 '-Dsonar.exclusions=app/Vendor/**,app/Plugin/**/Test/**,app/Test/**'
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_101 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: /usr/local/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /projectpath/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /projectpath/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.3
12:54:00.422 INFO  - Load global repositories
12:54:00.927 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=505ms
12:54:00.988 INFO  - User cache: /projectpath/.sonar/cache
12:54:01.016 INFO  - Exclude plugins: devcockpit, jira, pdfreport, views, report, buildstability, buildbreaker, scmstats
12:54:01.417 INFO  - Load plugins index
12:54:01.431 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=14ms
12:54:02.121 INFO  - Found project [MyProject] cache [Thu May 19 11:29:15 CEST 2016]
12:54:02.280 INFO  - Process project properties
12:54:02.723 INFO  - Load project repositories
12:54:03.461 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=738ms
12:54:03.485 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
12:54:03.629 INFO  - Load quality profiles
12:54:04.348 INFO  - Load quality profiles (done) | time=719ms
12:54:04.357 INFO  - Load active rules
12:54:09.383 INFO  - Load active rules (done) | time=5026ms
12:54:09.401 INFO  - Issues mode
12:54:09.401 INFO  - Scanning only changed files
12:54:09.405 INFO  - -------------  Scan MyProject
12:54:10.217 INFO  - Language is forced to php
12:54:10.238 INFO  - Load server rules
12:54:11.104 INFO  - Load server rules (done) | time=866ms
12:54:11.233 INFO  - Base dir: /projectpath/workspace
12:54:11.233 INFO  - Working dir: /projectpath/.sonar
12:54:11.235 INFO  - Source paths: app
12:54:11.235 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
12:54:11.236 INFO  - Index files
12:54:11.265 INFO  - Excluded sources: 
12:54:11.266 INFO  -   app/Vendor/**
12:54:11.266 INFO  -   app/Plugin/**/Test/**
12:54:11.266 INFO  -   app/Test/**
12:54:11.266 INFO  -   app/Test/**
12:54:11.266 INFO  - Included tests: 
12:54:11.266 INFO  -   app/Test/**
12:54:16.551 INFO  - 983 files indexed
12:54:16.552 INFO  - 12296 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
12:54:16.661 INFO  - Quality profile for php: Sonar way
12:54:17.180 INFO  - JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /projectpath/target/jacoco.exec
12:54:17.183 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /projectpath/target/jacoco-it.exec
12:54:17.220 INFO  - Sensor NoSonar and Commented out LOC Sensor
12:54:17.926 INFO  - Sensor NoSonar and Commented out LOC Sensor (done) | time=706ms
12:54:17.926 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
12:54:18.161 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=235ms
12:54:18.162 INFO  - Sensor PHPSensor
12:54:18.894 INFO  - 509 source files to be analyzed
12:54:28.909 INFO  - 265/509 files analyzed, current file: /projectpath/MyFile.php
12:54:38.479 INFO  - Sensor PHPSensor (done) | time=20317ms
12:54:38.479 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor
12:54:38.479 INFO  - 509/509 source files have been analyzed
12:54:38.480 INFO  - PHPUnit xml test report not found: app/junit-output.xml
12:54:38.480 INFO  - PHPUnit xml unit test coverage report not found: app/clover-coverage.xml
12:54:38.480 INFO  - No PHPUnit integration test coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.itReportPath' property)
12:54:38.480 INFO  - No PHPUnit overall coverage report provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.overallReportPath' property)
12:54:38.480 INFO  - Sensor PHPUnit Sensor (done) | time=1ms
12:54:38.480 INFO  - Load server issues
12:54:40.752 INFO  - Load server issues (done) | time=2272ms
12:54:40.753 INFO  - Performing issue tracking
12:54:43.215 INFO  - 1210/1210 components tracked
12:54:43.216 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 45.188s
Final Memory: 7M/215M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone have any idea why this upgrade has stopped the SonarQube scanner from commenting/analyzing our pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh, we forgot to install the github plugin on our new SonarQube instance...

The command output should include:

> Starting analysis of pull request:
>   https://github.com/Organization/OurRepository/pull/2940

If it doesn't, you're most likely missing the github plugin.